# How to get the edge of a polygon drawn on map within Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, polygon, draw, edges

I am working with Leaflet and Leaflet-Draw in Angular to draw some polygons on the Google Map. How can I implement a listener when the user clicks exactly on the edge of the drawn polygons and get the lat and lng of that edge. I know a similar situation can be implemented with Google Map API like the code below, but I can not find any source to help me implement the same thing in Leaflet.

`google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function (event) { console.log(event.edge) }`

Google Map Documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#PolyMouseEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who come across this question: I found a solution myself!
I didn't find anything directly from Leaflet draw library that I could use, so I defined the problem for myself as a trigonometry problem and solve it that way. 
I defined a function in which on polygon click, it converts the event.latlng and loops over polygon.getLatLngs()[0] taking a pair of A and B points. A is the first coordinates, B is the next and if it reaches to the end of array, B will be the first point. Then using Collinear Function of 3 points with x, y, I checked if the clicked x, y has a same slope as point A and B.(has to be rounded it up), if so, I would save that A and B point pair with their latLng information and further used it in my project.
Although this method works, I would appreciate if anybody would know a better solution or library built-in function that can be used instead. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

When the user clicks on the polygon you can loop through all corners and check if he clicked in the near of the corner.

```
poly.on('click', function(e){
  var latlng = e.latlng;
  var corners = poly.getLatLngs();
  if(!L.LineUtil.isFlat(corners)){ //Convert to a flat array
    corners = corners[0];
  }

    //Convert the point to pixels
    var point = mymap.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng);

  //Loop through each corner
  corners.forEach(function(ll){    
    //Convert the point to pixels
    var point1 = mymap.latLngToContainerPoint(ll);
    var distance =  Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point1.x - point.x, 2) + Math.pow(point.y - point1.y, 2));

    //Check if distance between pixels is smaller then 10
    if(distance < 10){
        console.log('corner clicked');
    }
  });
});
```

This is plain JS you have to convert it self to angular.

A alternativ is to place on each corner a DivMarker or a CircleMarker and fire a event if the marker is clicked.
Looks like: https://geoman.io/leaflet-geoman

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this is not what I am looking for. I know how to get the corners. Maybe I wasn't clear about my question. I want to be able to click on midway of each path (line) in a polygon and be able to detect it and do stuff with it.
For example, if a polygon has 6 corners and 6 lines, the very first line that has been created from point 0 to point 1 will be the line 0  and so on. So, once user click on that line, it will say event.edge = 0 which is the very first line that has been drawn by user. 
Please read the documentation on the Google link to understand better.